# How can I search for questions tagged [plotly] that have been answered?

Tags: support, search

How would I accomplish the following search? I want to find questions that are

1. Tagged with [plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly)
2. Have 1 or more answers

Is this possible?

Comment: [\[plotly\] answers:1..](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplotly%5D+answers%3A1..)?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How to find answered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201911/165261)

Answer (score 2):

As Lino states, searching for `[plotly] answers:1` will do the trick.

For future reference, note that on the search results page, you can click 'Advanced Search Tips' to get a list of possible query strings you can use. (Screenshot below). More information is also available in the Help Center article: [How do I search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)?

[image: Advanced Search Tips open]

Comment: That list could benefit from some annotation (or a link to the same).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Good point. I've added a link to the help center article on searching, which gives more info about some of the options available.